# Cannot make sendmail to use a remote SMTP server

Tags: email, sendmail, smtp

I followed the following guide on how to setup sendmail to use a remote SMTP server and authenticate: https://www.smtp2go.com/docs/sendmail/

However, sendmail shows that it sends emails out, but debug shows that it connects to localhost and not the remote host.

I execute the following command to send emails:

```
sendmail -X sendmail_log -fname=email_to_send_out_from@host1.com myemail@host1.com < /tmp/email.txt
```

My host 'host1.com' does only allow emails sent from 'email_to_send_out_from@host1.com'.

email.txt:

```
Subject: Terminal Email Send

Email Content line 1
Email Content line 2
```

This is where in the log file localhost is used:

```
07460 <<< Subject: Terminal Email Send
07460 <<<
07460 <<< Email Content line 1
07460 <<< Email Content line 2
07460 <<< [EOF]
07460 === CONNECT [127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: please post the relevant configuration files and logs.

Comment: My configuration is standard Ubuntu 14 sendmail and additions from that guide. I am going to add logs in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sendmail-8.12+: Non set root uid installation => sending via 127.0.0.1:25

"Sendmail by sendmail.org" before sendmail-8.12 used to be installed as set root uid program.  It had used to create endless security problems. Sendmail-8.12 to avoid such security risks passes messages to sendmail daemon running as root and listening at `127.0.0.1:25`.

If you want to test you configuration you may execute your test command as root with `-Am` added to sendmail's command line options.

Sendmail by default uses `submit.cf` configuration file and sends messages to `127.0.0.1:25`. Some command line options (including `-Am`) make sendmail use `sendmail.cf` configuration file but (usually) it requires root privileges to run correctly.

https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/security/secure-install/
http://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail

Comment: Did you not make a mistake there, when you mentioned 'sendmail.cf' 2 times? Do you mean sendmail.mc?

Comment: @Stein FIXED.  Thank you for making me aware.